# PHP OOP relations between classes

Tags: php, oop, relation

I'm starting to learn myself OOP with PHP. I am wondering about the following case. I've a class named "Article" (like a news article). So, the class Article has some attributes like title, excerpt, image, publication date etc. But, an article also has an author. And this author is stored in another table. In the news articles table, I store an author_id.

I'm thinking about the following setup:

```
<?php
class Article
{
  // all attributes...
  // ...

  /**
  * @var int Who the article has written
  */
  public $authorId = null;

  public static function getAuthorId() {
  //do SQL query and return id of author
  }
}

class Author
{
  // all attributes...
  // ...

  public static function getAuthorById() {
  //do SQL query and return name, e-mail of author, based on ID
  }
}
?>
```

Is this the best approach or should I create a method within the "article"-class to get all the info of the author?

I only want to display the authors name within the rest of the article (on the frontend). Should I do a join to the authors-table when retrieving the whole article, or should I get the authors name via the authors-class?

Comment: (sorry for bad english) No, you should create a method in Article class that accepts autor ID and checks articles that matches with autor ID.

Comment: Article and Author are 2 different entities, but Article needs  Author ID attribute for listing articles.

Comment: So, the article depends on the author? Or should I say, the article object is dependent on the author object ?

Comment: Thnx, but I mean I just want to display the authors name within an article.

Comment: get article form database using Article class, and use author id field (authorId) and get author using Author class: `$author->getAuthorById($article->authorId)`

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was trying to do. I was thinking about another approach: the method that retrieves the article... I could just make a join in that query to return/set the authors name as well within the Article class, but that's not the way to go I assume?

Comment: This will work but is not a good design because your domain class will contain data access code. Data access operations are best encapsulated in "repository" classes.

Comment: @jeyoung , you mean 'controllers'?

Comment: No, I mean data-access objects or repositories.